# How to pass jvm arguments to spring boot deploy in tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot

I use spring boot package to jar, and run `java -jar xxx.jar --logging.config=xxx.xml`.

Now i package to war and deploy in tomcat, how can i pass `logging.config` such arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these articles could be usefull for you:

- https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/set-heapmemory-jvm-arguments-tomcat/
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html

In a shorthand, there a two options. First one is to use tomcat global JAVA_OPTS:

- Use `Setenv.sh` file to set JVM  arguments to Tomcat instance
- same as above, but using `Catalina.sh`

The example change is like:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Xss228k -XX:+UseParallelGC"
```

Verify your changes by executing `ps -eaf|grep -i java` command

Second one is to use `Context` from Tomcat. Please refer to the `Context Parameters` [section of this document](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle, you can do the following:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=10 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100 -XX:MaxGCMinorPauseMillis=50 -server -noverify -Xshare:off -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false -XX:+EliminateLocks -XX:+UseBiasedLocking"]
```